# Why isn't the charge of an electron taken to be "$-1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ coulombs"

Tags: electrons, charge, definition, si-units, metrology

Even though we refer to electrons being negatively charged, why is it that we don't write the charge as "-1.6 × 10^-19 coulombs"?

Comment: How *do* we write it?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is it about the expression you wrote that concerns you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do write the charge of the electron that way. However "the elementary charge" $e$, is not the charge of the electron (in the most common convention) [see the wiki on "elementary charge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge). The elementary charge is the magnitude of the charge of the electron, or $-1$ times the charge of the electron. Usually $q_p$ denotes the charge of a particle $p$ when you do some kind of calculation of its motion or the field it creates or whatever. So when writing the charge of the electron we often write $q_e=-e$.

I know it's not a great system. I would have preferred for the charge of the electron to be defined as positive, but it's too late.

Comment: How would charge having positive sign be any better? Thanks

Comment: @DarthNandan Since electrons are the particles that actually move when current runs through a metal, current would be the same direction as the moving particles. Unlike in our current system where electrons move the opposite direction as current. And since the electron is the simplest stable charged particle, the "elementary charge" is defined in terms of the electron charge. It would have been more convenient if the "elementary charge" was actually just the same thing as the electron charge, instead of $-1$ times the electron charge.

Answer (score 1):

Well whether it be electric field / magnetic field produced by an electron or let's say the force experienced by an electron in an EM field we always take the charge on the electron with a negative sign .
So , for all our purposes in physics we do take the charge on the electron with the negative sign.
For example consider the electric field by an electron at rest,this is given by colomb's law  $\ F=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{e }{r^2}\hat{r} $
here , e=-1.6 ×$10^{-19}$ coulombs